# linking index.php file (inside the htdocs folder in Xampp) to navigation bar in the home.html file in Desktop?

Tags: php, html

I have a home.**html** file in my desktop which has a navigation bar in it. And I have the index.**php** file which is a contact form file. So in my website at the navigation panel there is button called "contact us". I want to open the index.php file when I click it which is inside the htdocs folder in Xampp.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you know what a hyperlink is? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks

Comment: Yes I know I linked it like that but when i open the live sever in Visual Studio of home.html and click the button linked to index.php The save as window pop asking where do you want save the file.?

Comment: It would have been sensible to mention that originally! Anyway you can't use visual studio to develop PHP programs - the live server doesn't support it, and the editor doesn't really support it properly either. Visual Studio is for .NET programs only. You can develop PHP with Visual Studio Code (a different application) if you install the necessary plugins, or you can use a dedicated PHP IDE - there are several on the market. And for a webserver to run the code you can use IIS or Apache, with PHP installed into them

Comment: It sounds like you already have xampp though, so please use the Apache server which comes with that, instead of the Visual Studio one.

Answer (score 0):

Link to your index.php by default is http://localhost/ or http://127.0.0.1/